# Index out of range error when comparing values

Tags: python

```
a=[8,24,3,20,1,17]
r=[]
for i in a:
    for j in a:
        s=a[i]-a[j]
        r.append(s)
print r
```

When I run this program
Why the index out of range error for this question?

Comment: `for i in a` iterates through the values in `a`. So in the first iteration `i==8`, and `a[8]` is trying to access an element out of the range of the list.

Comment: `for in` loops over elements, not indexes.

Comment: `for i in a` is looping over each element in a. `for j in a` is looping over the elements in a again. So for your code you would want to change `s=a[i]-a[j]` to `s=i-j` as `i` and `j` are already the values you are trying to grab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `s = i - j` instead of `s = a[i] - a[j]`:

```
a=[8,24,3,20,1,17]
r=[]
for i in a:
    for j in a:
        s = i - j
        r.append(s)
print r
```

Output:

```
[0, -16, 5, -12, 7, -9, 16, 0, 21, 4, 23, 7, -5, -21, 0, -17, 2, -14, 12, -4, 17, 0, 19, 3, -7, -23, -2, -19, 0, -16, 9, -7, 14, -3, 16, 0]
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/EiLt/0)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the values, you should do

```
for i in range(len(a)):
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `j` are already elements from your lists. No need to index `a`.

So, instead use `s = i-j`

---

Your issue is that `a[i]` becomes `a[8]` at the first iteration, which is out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `j` are **values**, and you are mistaking them for **indices**.

`i` and `j` start as 8 (your list's first element). Naturally, `a[8]` gives you an error since your list's size is lower than this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because when you do

```
`for i in list:`
```

`i` is not an index, but the actual number.

Try doing

```
a=[8,24,3,20,1,17]
r=[]
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    for j, y in enumerate(a):
        s = a[i]-a[j]
        r.append(s)
print r
```

or

```
a=[8,24,3,20,1,17]
r=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        s = a[i]-a[j]
        r.append(s)
print r
```